# Keep an item on the first row in a wrapped list using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to create a row layout with the following features:

The first item in the row has a minimum size, but expands to fill any unused space.

There are several dynamic elements after the first one, of variable length.  They should share the same row while there is space for it, but if there isn't, they should all wrap together to a new row.

There's an element that should always be at the right end of the top row, regardless of whether the dynamic elements have wrapped to a new row or not.

Here's what that might look like using flexbox:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="start-item">start item</div>
  <div id="end-item">end item</div>
  <div class="dynamic-items">
    <div class="dynamic-item">these</div>
    <div class="dynamic-item">are</div>
    <div class="dynamic-item">dynamic</div>
    <div class="dynamic-item">items</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dynamic-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

#start-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#end-item {
  order: 0; // works for single line

  // works for wrapped lines
  margin-left: auto;
  order: 1;
}
```

There's one problem, and that is that I can only get the end button in the right position if it's after the dynamic items if the lines are wrapped, and before them if everything is on one line.  You can see this demonstrated in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgmort/6zkxmrj0/.

I put in a checkbox that toggles the order -- the unchecked state gives the desired result if the lines have not wrapped, and the checked state gives the desired result if the lines are wrapped.

How can I get this to work for both conditions?

Comment: so the end item should always stay at the top right?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes

Comment: Note: though I am looking for a non-JS solution, I have found that the https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries offers a very performant way of solving the problem with minimal JS.  See http://jsfiddle.net/bgmort/6zkxmrj0/107/

Answer (score 1):

If you keep everything in the fiddle exactly as it is, but change a couple of css properties, this will work.

Add `position: relative; padding-right: 85px;` to `#container`.

Add `position: absolute; right: 5px;` to `#end-item`.

This works as long as `#end-item` doesn't have a dynamic width.

Here is a forked fiddle that is working. http://jsfiddle.net/q09xb41h/